# Constructing RSACryptoServiceProvider from X509Certificate2 without LDAP request being made

Tags: c#, x509certificate2, rsacryptoserviceprovider

When the line to extract the public key is executed, an LDAP request is sent:

```
        this.certificate = new X509Certificate2(buffer);
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey key = this.certificate.PublicKey;
```

> 50    0.853745000 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx LDAP    404 searchRequest(1) "" baseObject

...which I believe is authenticating the currently logged on user.  I really need to avoid this call, as on a customer system this causes a long delay because of network configuration.

I'm assuming it's attempting to do some authentication around some kind of key store, but as in this case the certificate is all contained in the buffer provided, all I want is for the key to be used without this request being sent.

All I actually want is to create an RSACryptoServiceProvider from the private key in the certificate.  I tried a few methods I've found on here involving GetPrivateKey, but struggled to get anything to work.

Thanks in advance!

*EDIT* Test program:

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(@"E:\Temp\Cert.cer");
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey key = certificate.PublicKey;
    }
```

The certificate I tested with can be found here: [Cert.cer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106407239/Cert.cer)

Yes, it's not the strongest signature or key, before I get comments!

Thanks again.

EDIT: I actually worked around this by using a suggestion to use BouncyCastle.  I use this to parse the certificate:

```
X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = parser.ReadCertificate(buffer);
```

I then extract the modulus and exponent and push them into a Microsoft RSAParameters:

```
RsaKeyParameters key = (RsaKeyParameters)cert.GetPublicKey();

// Construct a microsoft RSA crypto service provider using the public key in the certificate
RSAParameters param = new RSAParameters();
param.Exponent = key.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
param.Modulus = key.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
```

I can then construct the Microsoft RSACryptoServiceProvider from this:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    provider.ImportParameters(param);
    byte[] rsaBlock = provider.Encrypt(preMasterSecret, false);
    this.Client.Writer.Write(rsaBlock);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that this line performs LDAP query? Can you show us more code involved?

Comment: I've reproduced this with a simple test program and self-signed certificate.  I'll update the question with the test code.

Comment: And yes, when I step over the second, line, I get the following in Wireshark: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106407239/Wireshark%20from%20private%20key.png)

Comment: Use BouncyCastle as a workaround. But if you happen to find the reason for this LDAP request I'm dying to know.

Comment: I've asked this question on the Microsoft support forum.  I'm considering escalating it and getting some official support there too.

I'll certainly take a look at BouncyCastle though, thanks for that!

Comment: Thanks Pepo - I did end up using BouncyCastle to accomplish this in the end.  I'll post some snippets below.

Comment: ...added my workaround to my original question.

Comment: I never got anything back on why the LDAP request was being sent.  I'd forgotten about this, but I think it''s time to close it down.  Bouncycastle was the answer, thank you again @pepo

Comment: @DarrenSandford I'm glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got any other response, so here's the Bouncycastle implementation I used.

```
X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate cert = parser.ReadCertificate(buffer);
```

I then extract the modulus and exponent and push them into a Microsoft RSAParameters:

```
RsaKeyParameters key = (RsaKeyParameters)cert.GetPublicKey();

// Construct a microsoft RSA crypto service provider using the public key in the certificate
RSAParameters param = new RSAParameters();
param.Exponent = key.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
param.Modulus = key.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
```

I can then construct the Microsoft RSACryptoServiceProvider from this:

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    provider.ImportParameters(param);
    byte[] rsaBlock = provider.Encrypt(preMasterSecret, false);
    this.Client.Writer.Write(rsaBlock);
}
```